# List of people who lose a child in תנ"ך

Tags: tanach, death, children-parenting

Full list of people, based on pshat who lost a child in תנ"ך?

Comment: Mesushelach and maybe others in that geneology

Comment: I take it you’re not counting Yaakov, who thought he lost a child?

Comment: @DonielF he definitely did lose a child. No one could find Yosef for decades!

Answer (score 9):

- Adam and Eve (Genesis 4:25):* their son Cain killed their other son Abel
- Terah (Genesis 11:28): his son Haran died in his lifetime
- Judah (Genesis 38:7,10):* his sons Er and Onan died after marrying Tamar
- Pharaoh and all the Egyptians (Exodus 12:30):<sup>1</sup> lost their firstborn in the tenth plague
- Aaron (Leviticus 10:2):* his sons Nadab and Abihu died when bringing a fire offering
- Zur (Numbers 25:15):<sup>3</sup> his daughter Cozbi was killed while he was killed at a later time (31:8)
- Mother of Sisera (Judges 5:28): described as being alive after Sisera died
- Jephthah (Judges 11:39):<sup>1</sup> he fulfilled his vow to sacrifice his daughter, apparently killing her
- Eli (1 Samuel 4:11):* his sons Hofni and Phinehas died in battle with Philistines
- Mother of Agag (1 Samuel 15:33): described as being bereaved when Agag died
- Saul (1 Samuel 31:2): his sons died shortly before him in the war against the Philistines
- David (2 Samuel 12:18, 13:32, 18:15):* he lost an unnamed child, Amnon, and Absalom
- A prostitute (1 Kings 3:19): two prostitutes had two sons, and one of them died
- Jeroboam (1 Kings 14:17):<sup>2</sup> his son Abijah died of a sickness
- Hiel of Bethel (1 Kings 16:34):<sup>1</sup> lost his sons by building Jericho
- Mesha (2 Kings 3:27): sacrificed his son
- An unnamed woman (2 Kings 6:28): ate her son and wanted to eat her neighbor's son
- Athaliah (2 Kings 11:1): her son was killed in battle
- Ahaz (2 Kings 16:3): put his sons through fire (assuming this means he killed them)
- Manasseh (2 Kings 21:6): also put his sons through fire (same caveat)
- Zedekiah (2 Kings 25:7):<sup>1</sup> his sons were slaughtered before his eyes
- Job (Job 1:19):* all of his sons and daughters died
- Naomi (Ruth 1:5): her two sons died in Moab
- Ephraim (1 Chronicles 7:22): mourned over his children

<sup>*</sup> <sub>mentioned by the OP [Josh Silverblatt](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15080/josh-silverblatt)</sub>

<sup>1</sup> <sub>noted by [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa)</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>noted by [Gary](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1952/gary)</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>noted by [DonielF](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/9682/donielf)</sub>

Comment: I'm revoking ownership. Add whatever you want @Yez DonielF

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91693/discussion-on-answer-by-b-a-list-of-people-who-lose-a-child-in-).